# Capture https header from Java

Tags: java, https

Sorry in advance for my not-perfect english.

I'm trying to capture the http/https traffic in real-time from a Java program. 
Thanks to Jnetpcap library, I managed to do it quite easily but, for the https traffic, I don't manage to get just the headers of the packets, even if I ask to capture all the tcp packets without port filter. I don't understand how sofwares like Fiddler manage to do it, e.g. to have the domain name like facebook.com or google.com.

Is there a way to do it in Java ?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that HTTPS is working as designed, by preventing you from reading the data if the client doesn't trust your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS, Fiddler uses its own SSL certificate. So from both the client and server view the connection is secure. Fiddler is a Man-In-the-Middle (Proxy), able to decrypt incoming data from the client and then encrypting it for the server.

Comment: Ok ! And is it difficult to implement this type of proxy in Java ?